# how to show current date and 200 days+current date in php

Tags: php, date

I  have a project where I can show current date and time. After that I can show current date + 200 days after a date in PHP. I'm new in PHP programing

Comment: `echo date('n/j/Y',strtotime('now +200day'));`

Comment: Please take the time to do some basic searching before posting here. Date manipulation is a pretty basic topic and is already covered at length here, in the official PHP manual, and elsewhere.  Also, when it _is_ actually appropriate to post something here, you should try to actually ask a question instead of just posting your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime();
$currentDate = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$dt->add(new DateInterval("P200D")); 
$futureDate = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $currentDate;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $futureDate;
?>
```

**Program Output**

```
2018-04-27 17:11:57
2018-11-13 17:11:57
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/996235